# xskak and NAGs/Chess Informant symbols

Tags: chess

I can't for the life of me figure out a proper way to handle [NAGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_Annotation_Glyphs) (Numeric Annotation Glyphs) and/or Chess Informant symbols with `xskak`.

I'm writing a document where I'm handling a lot of variations, so I'm staying away from `\newchessgame` and `\mainline` for the most part and putting everything in `\variation{}`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak,mathtools,xspace}

\def\invar#1{{\variation[invar]{#1}}}
\def\onlymovesymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\def\onlymove{\xskakcomment{\onlymovesymbol}\xspace}
\def\onlymoveNAG{$7}%$ stop highlighting, Emacs+AUCTeX!

\begin{document}
\variation{1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Nf6 4.Ng5 d5\onlymove 5.Nxe4}

\variation{%
  1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5 4.c3 Nf6 5.d4 exd4 6.cxd4 Bb4+ 7.Nc3 Nxe4 
  8.O-O Nxc3 9.bxc3 d5} 
\iffalse %This doesn't even compile:
  \invar{9... Bxc3 10.Qb3 d5\onlymove 11.Bxd5 O-O} 
\fi
\end{document}
```

If one compiles this the square shows up in the first variation, but "5 Nxe4" is printed without the figurine for the "N".

Am I correct in assuming that NAGs only work when xskak actually parses the moves (i.e. only with `\mainline{}`)?

If that's the case, I can't see how I won't have to use `\xskakcomment`.  I know I'm doing *something* wrong, but I can't for the life of me decipher how one is supposed to accomplish this.

PS: For those who use Emacs + AUCTeX and find this question by searching.  Look at the options beginning with `LaTeX-verbatim`. You can consider adding `\mainline`, `\variation[invar]` and `\variation[outvar]` to the list of verbatim macros with delimiters if you want to use NAGs without AUCTeX spilling the colour for maths mode all over your buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You loose the figurine of the move as (x)skak needs to see the spaces between the moves, but your command is eating it. Use braces to prevent this, or use the $7 instead of a command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}
\variation{1.e4 $1  e5 $2 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 $7 Nf6 4.Ng5 d5\onlymove{} 5.Nxe4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

skak changes catcodes. So you shouldn't read the argument before this has been done. Define your `\invar` like this:

```
  \def\invar{\variation[invar]}
```

And naturally add braces after the `\onlymove` there too.

Comment: One solution I've come up with for dealing with subvariations is `\def\subv{\variation[invar]{}} \def\endsubv{\variation[outvar]{}}` used like this: `\variation{<stuff>} \subv \variation{<other stuff>} \endsubv`. Ugly, but it kind of works. At least until you get three nested levels of variations (e.g. if you're GM Robert Hübner :D)

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing there and why. What's wrong with using \variation[invar]{moves} directly?

Comment: I dislike the inconsistency it leads to in the source file: `{\variation[invar]{moves} blah blah explanation \variation{more moves}}`.  It just doesn't look *right* that a subvariation starts with `invar` but continues without it. I find that it makes it harder for me to verify that I've written what I wanted.

Comment: Hm. I see. Well I can't keep the effect of invar local to the `\variation` command, this would only be possible with printing commands completly under the control of `xskak` (like `\printchessgame`). But you can use braces: `{\variation[invar]{..}}`. You can also define commands which changes the levels like this: `\newcommand\invar{\xskakset{invar}}\newcommand\outvar{\xskakset{outvar}}`